# In updating a question, is it better to comment so people can see the original form, or just edit the question?

Tags: discussion

For instance:
[What's good form for calling views within a module (template, etc)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/24565/5569)

If I have more information regarding a problem, or in the above case, something else I'm observing, is it better to update the original question or post a comment?

Comment: In this specific case, your comment/observation is would be worthy of a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is something relevant for the question, it is better to edit the question; by relevant, I mean something that could change the given answers. Comments should be used for something less relevant, such as "I am not using anymore this module, and I cannot verify if the given answers are correct."

This is in the case the question doesn't have any answer. If there are already answers, it is rather preferable not to alter the question, in the case that would make the answers not valid anymore. This is especially true when the question has been asked time ago, and who answered would not get back to change the answer they gave.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification!